# Can I get the length of a stepEntry.value

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm iterating over a map in thymeleaf and I was wondering if there is a way to get the length of the stepEntry.value.

The max length of the input field where this value is entered should be equal to the length of this stepEntry.value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you pass the stepEntry to view? i mean is this the name of an object that pass to view?

Comment: stepEntry is the name of the entry in a map. So whe I say stepEntry.key, I'm talking about the key of an entry in the map. stepEntry.value would mean the value for that entry.

Comment: Yes, you can get the length of a stepEntry.value, but you've not given enough information for anyone to help.  What kind of object is `stepEntry.value`. (What types are you storing in your map?)

Comment: It's a plain string. I'm trying to get the length of the string, the amount of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you don't try this way?

```
<input type="text" th:maxlength="${#strings.length(stepEntry.value)}">
```